# How to know what method to use when finding resultant forces?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, vectors, statics

I am quite confused as to what method should be used when finding resultant forces. Here are two examples of a question that asks to find the resultant force.

[image: Example 1]

One requires the parallelogram law to be used.

[image: Example 2]

The other requires finding the total in Fx and Fy.

So how do I identify which method I am supposed to use if its not stated during an exam? The questions seem very similar to each other. Is there specific details that I should bear in mind when it comes to the parallelogram law? Thank you in advance and sorry if this is a bit messy. It's my first time using this website.

Comment: What is the difference between  "parallelogram law" and "finding the total in Fx and Fy"? How would you do one or another?

Comment: The two methods give identical answers. (That's rather the whole point) If it's not stated during an exam, you can use either method.

Comment: I agree with Chris.  Note that on an exam, you should use whichever method is faster, because the exam is being timed.

Comment: Both are examples of [vector addition](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorAddition.html#:~:text=Vector%20addition%20is%20the%20operation,tail%20to%20the%20free%20head.)

Answer (score 1):

There is practically **no** difference between the two methods. However, while using, there are some cases where one method will be more helpful than the other.

If you **know the *direction* of the resultant force or vector, and the *angles* made by the given forces or vectors with the resultant**, then you can use the second method. However, you don't have to resolve into the x- and the y- components. You can just resolve each force into their components along the direction of resultant, and add them up to give the magnitude of the resultant force. Be careful about signs. An example of this type of problem may be this:

> Two persons on different sides of a river, pull a boat towards themselves by means of a string. The boat moves forward in a straight line. The forces make  $\theta$ and $\phi $ with the direction of motion of the boat. Find the resultant force on the boat.

Here, you know the direction of the resultant force. Just resolve the two given forces into their cosine and add them to get the resultant force.

In case where you ***don't* know the direction of resultant**, you can use either method. In this case, you'll **have** to find the x- and the y-components, if you are using the second one. **Both shall give the correct answer, and both are accepted.**

Answer (score 1):

You can use whatever method is quick and clear, but working with components is systematic, can be used with any number of vectors, and can be extended to 3D.  Just remember that $F_x$ is F cos(θ) and $F_y$ is F sin(θ).  (I have a spreadsheet that can do sums or products of vectors using components in 2D or 3D.)

Answer (score 1):

Using a parallelogram provides insight, but if you want foolproof, then write down the force equation balance for *x* and *y* directions and then confirm that you have the same number of equations as unknowns.

Each time it asks for the *total* force you need two equations, one for the *x* axis and one for the *y* axis and then combine them to get the magnitude with $F = \sqrt{F_x^2 + F_y^2}$

But if the direction of a force is known, only one equation is needed as only the component of the force along this direction is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of questions you can always proceed with **resolution of vectors**...the best method possible.

And in this method you can choose the axis according to your wish but yes they must be perpendicular to each other...and always be careful with which axis the angle is given...

*The axis with which the angle(x) is given always takes the cos(x) component whereas the other takes sin(x) component*

Hope this helps you...